# What should be done after getting this error : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, string, integer

```
 def tokenizer(text):
       text = text.lower()
       tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
       tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```

How do I solve this error? what should I do about the integer value in the text?

Below is the text that needs to be tokenized

> 14\n item 8.item 7. management's discussion and analysis of financial condition and results\n        of operation\n\n\nyear ended december 28, 1997 compared to the year ended december 29, 1996\n\n\n     in november 1996, the company initiated a major restructuring and growth\nplan designed to substantially reduce its cost structure and grow the business\nin order to restore higher levels of profitability for the company. by july\n1997, the company completed the major phases of the restructuring plan. the\n$225.0 million of annualized cost savings anticipated from the restructuring\nresults primarily from the consolidation of administrative functions within the\ncompany, the rationalization of manufacturing and warehouse facilities\n(including a reduction in the number of production facilities from 26 to 8 and\nwarehouses from 61 to 18), the elimination of over 6,000 positions

Comment: either str(text).lower() or make sure that text is of type string with def tokenizer(text:str)

Comment: Just convert the `int` to `string` using `str(text).lower()`.

Comment: Using `str(text)` as people are suggesting is just covering up the fact that there's some kind of mistake in the calling code -- the thing you're passing to this function is definitely not the paragraph from your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just cast the text value into a string using `str()`
the code will be as follow

```
 def tokenizer(text):
       text = str(text).lower()
       tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
       tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```

you are getting this error because python is handling the numbers as `int` and the `int` class has no function `.lower()` so first you need to cast this integer into a string to be able to use functions in the class `str` like `.lower()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be passing an integer into `tokenizer(text)`. All you have to do is convert `text` to a string using `str(text).lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the 'text' parameter is a String? I think this kind of error should occurs if the type of text variable is int... Debug it or try to test if it really a String:

```
def tokenizer(text):
   if isinstance(text, str):
     text = text.lower()
     tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
     tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
   else:
     ValueError('Sorry...')
```

This works -> '7'.lower()